# Exception if input is invalid in Java. For, example Age

Tags: java, validation, exception

I want to throw an exception in order to let the user know that the age value input should be between 1 and 120. Find below the example.

Is there a better way to throw an exception?

```
public class Lesson18Encapsulation3 {

    private int age;
    private String name;
    private int salary;

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {

        if ( age < 0 && age >= 120) 

            this.age = age;
        throw new IllegalArgumentException (" age can not be negative or more than 120");

//getters and setters

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

```java
public class Lesson18Encapsulation4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Lesson18Encapsulation3 emp = new Lesson18Encapsulation3();

        emp.setAge(220);
        emp.setName("None");

        System.out.println( "age : " + emp.getAge());
        System.out.println( "name : " + emp.getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that if the age is not valid, you shouldn't do `this.age = age;`. You may also consider using Java Validation Api, an example here : https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation

Comment: Are you sure about the if clause for the age? I doubt there are people with age of -8. :)

Comment: This is just to protect Data from misuse. Someone can change the age via setter method.   

   
        Lesson18Encapsulation3 emp = new Lesson18Encapsulation3();

        emp.setAge(220);  // Error: Throw new IllegalArgumentException
        emp.setAge(-8);  // Erro:  Throw new IllegalArgumentException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition is wrong. You want to set the age only if the range is between `0` and `120`:

```
if (age >= 0 && age < 120) {
    this.age = age;
} else throw new IllegalArgumentException("Age can not be negative or more than 120");
```

Alternatively (note the changed `||` operator which means **or**):

```
if (age < 0 || age >= 120) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Age can not be negative or more than 120");  
}
this.age = age;
```

Throwing an exception itself upon wrong input is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 4):

In principle, what you are doing here is an instance of [design by contract](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YqqkAu6hN7A): You are defining a pre-condition for your method.

**A) Wrong Condition**

Your condition is wrong. You want to throw the exception in exactly the opposite case:

```
if(age < 0 || age >= 120) {
   // Throw exception
}
```

(This was also pointed out by @Nikolas in an earlier post)

**B) Make Design by Contract Explicit**

I'd make this explicit by providing an Assertion-method:

```
private void setAge(int age) {
    assertCorrectAge(age);
    this.age = age;
}

private void assertCorrectAge(int age) {
    if(age < 0 || age >= 120) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(" ... ");
    }
}
```

Some people will suggest to use Java's build in `assert` keyword. I suggest to not do that, because it is disabled in most JVM versions (so it doesn't fire).

**C) Use a library**

Having many assertion method for checking pre-conditions, adds up to a lot of boilerplate code. You could have a library take care of this (for example [Google's Guava](https://github.com/google/guava)):

```
public void setAge(int age) {
    Preconditions.checkArgument(age >= 0, "negative age: %s", age);
    Preconditions.checkArgument(age < 120, "age too high: %s", age);
    this.age = age;
}
```

Comment: **A** brings nothing new. **B** is not necessary - much better would be a use of Java Validation API. Agreed that avoiding the `assert` keyword is a good way. **C** I recommend again the Java Validation API rather than Guava.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I disagree particularly regarding **B**: It is an improvement towards readibility and makes the intent clearer. Also, it encapsulates the check of the pre-condition. Regarding **A**: I was not aware that you had pointed out this as well. I apologize and will edit my post to reflect your contribution.

Comment: Well **A** brings the correct if-clause (which I assume is wrong in the question). **C** is a suggestion. I thought Java Validation API could be a little bit too much.

Comment: Your comment on **C** makes me think a bit more: It might be true for a Java EE context. But in general Java, I have not seen it used for the checks of invariants, pre- and post conditions. Can you provide an example application/ reference?